# When i process my data in my local host server it is getting read very fast but when i connect my database to mongolab data is getting read very slow

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

When I process my data in my localhost server it is getting read very fast but when I connect my database to mongolab data is getting read very slow. how can i improve the speed of getting my data to read? Is there any possibility that data can be read fast.

Comment: What do you mean by process here? Find out what makes your queries slow? Is it your network or you need any index?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by very Slow.
2. Have you indexed the relevant field you do a find() on ? Looks like you have indexed in Mongod but not on mongoLab 3. How many docs you have in your collection ?